# Como criar um array com dados a partir de uma table html?

Tags: jquery, html

Preciso colocar os dados da **table** html em um **array**. O cenário atual não permite eu adicionar `class` ou `id` para as tags `<td>` (o que me facilitaria muito), mais adiante eu iniciei o código **jquery** mas não sei como prosseguir.
**HTML**

```
<table id="tb1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Bola1</th>
        <th>Bola2</th>
        <th>Bola3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>10</td><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>4</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>2</td><td>6</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**JQUERY** 
    Seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('.btnok').on('click', function () {
            var dados = [];                
            var table = $("#tb1 tbody");

            table.find("tr").each(function (indice) {                    
                $(this).find('td').each(function (indice) {

                    dados[indice] = new Object();
                    dados[indice][indice] = $(this).text();

                });

            });
        });

});
```

**Eu espero retornar um JSON:**

```
[
    {"Bola1":"3","Bola2":"10","Bola3":"5"},
    {"Bola1":"1","Bola2":"4","Bola3":"3"},
    {"Bola1":"3","Bola2":"2","Bola3":"6"}
]
```

Comment: pode dar um exemplo do array resultante que você espera ter?

Comment: Eu alterei o post e adicionei um exemplo do que eu quero retornar (JSON)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar uma função para verificar e atribuir os dados da tabela à um objeto e, posteriormente, incluir em uma lista. No código abaixo, criei uma função `tableToJSON` que recebe como parâmetro  o `seletor` da tabela e retorna uma lista de objetos baseada na mesma.

```js
console.log(tableToJSON("table"));

function tableToJSON(tableSelector){
  var array = new Array();
  var $thead = $(tableSelector).find("thead > tr > th");
  var $tbody =$(tableSelector).find("tbody > tr");

  $tbody.each(function(x){
    var obj = new Object();  
    var $row = $(this);
    $thead.each(function(i){
      var attributeName = $(this).text();
      obj[attributeName] = $row.find("td")[i].innerText
    });
    array.push(obj);
  });  
  return array;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Coluna 1</th>
    <th>Coluna 2</th>
    <th>Coluna 3</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr><td>Teste 1</td><td>Teste 1</td><td>Teste 3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Teste 4</td><td>Teste 5</td><td>Teste 6</td></tr>
  
</tbody>
</table>
```

Veja funcionando no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0h7dxpks/)

Comment: Perfeito! Isso mesmo que eu precisava. Obrigado!